# Multivalued key in erd?

Tags: database, erd

Is it possible for erd to have multivalued primary key?

If so, how do i treat them when mapping to relational schema?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are talking about composite or compound keys. On a high level, these are keys that are composed of multiple columns such as (`id, date, name`). You would need to create the same columns on the referenced table and create the same key.

```
*Table2*

id, date, name

Index1: (id, date, name)

*Table2*

id, date, name, favorite_color

Index2: (id, date, name) references Table2.Index1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a Composite attribute as a Primary key but **Multivalued attribute cannot be taken as a Primary key**.

*Because Multivalued Attribute is taken as an abnormality and it is resolved by making another entity of that attribute*.